# Is it true to use while(true) with thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, while-loop, cpu

I have a project that has multiple thread for receiving TCP message. The number of thread depends on user and the funtions inside thread makes too much calculation. My thread function is something like ;

```
    void *TcpMessage() 
    {
    while(1) 
    {
       pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); 
       pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock); 
      switch(thecase)
      {
       Case1:
       ...  // matrix calculation
       break;
       Case2:
       ... // Integral and some histogram calculation
       break;
      } 
        default: 
        break;
     } 
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&cv); 
    }
```

Is it true to use infinite while loop? Is it bad for performance? If it is wrong what can i do instead  of it?

Comment: the question is not quite clear. Can you clarify why you think you need an infinite loop and why you think using an infinite loop would be a problem?

Comment: This depends heavily on the context.

Comment: It might be bad for performance if your thread workload conditions are not met by some incoming event or other incoming data, but you still loop instead of doing an efficient wait. This is called spinning and can raise CPU usage a lot. However, if you do an efficient wait until some request for work comes in to wake up the thread, then infinite loop is ok as long as you also provide for an exit condition. Just the tip of the iceberg :)

Comment: I presume there is a case condition handling that will break out of the loop with a break, a goto, a return, a throw, a std::terminate, or a std::exit.  I vaguely recall some C++ language esoterica that makes non-terminating infinite loops *undefined behavior*.

Comment: All my threads run in parallel and it must always run. I think that may be it is bad idea for cpu performance. Because using while true loop lock one core and i have to many thread @idclev 463035818

Comment: what do you mean with "bad for cpu performance" ? You get most out of your cpu when it is running at 100%, of course you want to use that 100% to do something useful, not just to run a loop that does nothing, but from the code you posted it is not possible to know what is going on inside that loop

Comment: In while loop i have mutex and condition variable for synchronization. When break it unlocks mutex @DNT

Comment: @Eljay its not esotherics. An infinite loop without side effect is UB. Here is an example where clang makes use of that: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: @Eljay More precisely, a compiler is allowed to optimize based on the assumption that every loop will end. Unlike most other optimizations, the compiler does not need to prove "as-if". So, for example, if there are no side-effects and the only way out of the loop is a conditional `return` statement, the compiler can reduce the loop to that one `return` statement, even if the condition is not known to ever be true. (All these details are a mess, so the standard just calls it "undefined behavior", allowing compilers to do what they want.)

Comment: I edit my code to be more clear,  @id 463035818

Comment: Then what do i use instead of while true @JaMiT

Comment: I suggest you loop on the condition variable wait after checking again if the wakeup condition is true to avoid "spurious wakeups"

Comment: Your code, as written, locks the mutex on each iteration of the loop, but it only ever unlocks the mutex _outside_ the loop.  That can't be a good thing. Also, the `default` switch case is _outside_ the `switch` statement. So, I would not expect your example to compile even if you filled in the `...` with actual code. Please consider editing your question so that the example is more faithful to the actual code that you are trying to understand.